# Optaplanner FieldAccessingSolutionCloner: How to model an externalized traveltime matrix?

Tags: optaplanner

In the context of the [vehicle-routing](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.20.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#vehicleRouting)- or TSP-problem: Let's say we want to externalise the travel-time between two locations into a cost-matrix problem fact.

We can rewrite the `distanceTo`-method of the GeoLocation-class to a simple lookup of the value in the matrix. But to do that we need to store a reference of the matrix-instance in the GeoLocation-instances.

What impact does this have on the [cloning of the solution](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.20.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#fieldAccessingSolutionCloner) and associated planning entities? Is the matrix going to be deeply cloned / will different planning-entities point to different matrix-instances during planning? Of course this should be avoided as the matrix does not change during planning and deep-cloning it might inflict a performance decrease. Instead, each GeoLocation's matrix-reference should point to the same matrix-object in the memory.

Is the `FieldAccessingSolutionCloner` handling this appropriately or do we need to provide our own `SolutionCloner`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SolutionCloner does a **planning clone**, which doesn't clone problem facts, unless the problem facts references the planning solution or a planning entity.
**Your class model should be designed such at there is no need to planning clone your distance matrix.**

The VRP example in optaplanner-examples doesn't clone it's distance matrix (the Location instances aren't planning cloned).

It's important to understand that anything that directly or indirectly references a planning entity or the planning solution, must be planning cloned, or changes to the working solution will affect the best solution, corrupting it.

Comment: thanks! I'm conscious that the distance matrix should not be cloned, because it does not change during planning. But currently I have a `private CostMatrix traveltimes` field in my `@PlanningEntity Visit` class. Do I need to do anything to instruct the SolutionCloner **not** to create a copy of that matrix when cloning the visit?

Comment: No, you don't. It will look at that class and as long as it has no pointer back to an class that must be planning cloned, it won't be planning cloned. It's opt-in, with @DeepPlanningClone, not opt-out.